# Pass value to function on blur event using knockout

Tags: knockout.js, lost-focus

I have 2 inputbox and both will call same function on the blur event like below

```
 <td>
                <input id="txtDate1" data-bind="value:Date1, event: { blur: ValidateData }"  />

            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="txtDate2" data-bind="value: Date2, event: { blur: ValidateData }" />
            </td>
```

in my view model i have created function `validateData`

```
 this.ValidateDate = function () {

        var txtData = $('#txtDate1').val();

        if (!valid_date(txtData )) {

               alert("Date not valid");
                $(this).focus();

 };
```

To this function i want to pass actual value of textbox on lost focus. My problem is that i dont know which value to pass to this function.

How can i achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very easy you can do it like this

```
data-bind="value:Date1, event: { blur: ValidateData.bind($data,Date1) }"
```

And your function

```
this.ValidateDate = function (myval) {
    // your code
};
```

Comment: use some value i only given here example

Comment: In th click binding of course. See [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you add a parameter, knockout will pass the `current model value` observable. In your case it will pass the `parent` of `Date1` and `Date2`. You can use the following to differenciate `Date1` from `Date2`:

```
<input id="txtDate1" data-bind="value:Date1, 
       event: { blur: 
                    function (data, event) { 
                        ValidateDate('Date1', data, event) 
                    } 
              }"  />

this.ValidateDate = function (whichDate, data, event) {

    if (!valid_date(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(data[whichDate]))) {
           alert("Date not valid");
            $(this).focus();
};
```

See [doc](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html):

> When calling your handler, Knockout will supply the current model value as the first parameter